# C# + SQL Select + dataset + dataadapter = out of memory

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, dataadapter

I'm currently trying to use C# to read through an SQL DB.  To do so, I use OleDB with a select statement.  This goes into a dataset, which then populates a data adapter.  I then iterate through each row and calculate stuff.

First of all, I feel like there's a better/more efficient way of doing this because I NEVER actually write back to the SQL DB. I just calculate based on what I'm selecting.

Anyways, past a certain point I get out of memory errors and/or an error from Ssms.exe saying "a new guard page for the stack cannot be created."

From the other questions I've seen, I need to use DataReader but I can't seem to get it to work the same way as the data adapter (which I suppose isn't that surprising).

The code I have now:

```
OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(@"SQLDB connection string here");

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = <selectstatement here>
        cmd.Connection = myConn;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        myConn.Close();
```

---

```
     foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
            {
                  //do stuff
```

I guess my question is twofold, like I said above.  One would DataReader solve my problem and allow me to iterate through the data, and two how do I adapt the first code snippet above to support that?

Also, since I've seen it elsewhere, I'm using x64 on the application.

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of MSDN page describing `OleDbDataReader` class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx - there is an example of usage there. Of course you can do whatever you need in the loop- populate dataset  or whatsoever. But probably you also no't need dataset at all - it depends on your concrete task and need of "go back in data" in your computations.

Comment: Yes, it's entirely possible to use a `DataReader` instead to loop through the results of your query and do your calculation.  We'd really need to know what your query is and what you're attempting to calculate in order to give an answer.  It's also possible that you might be able to do the calculation in the SQL and thus reduce the amount of data returned from the DB.

Comment: Use a dataset only if you need to work with your data in a disconnected way. Otherwise you can loop over the datareader and save a lot of memory. Anyway, how many tables and rows have you got in your data source? If your query retrieves tons of data you should think at an alternative (maybe paged) data loading.

Comment: I saw that MSDN page about OleDBDataReader.I was confused about was how I'd adapt code like this:

                    if (dr["column1"] == DBNull.Value && dr["column2"] != DBNull.Value) 

to check for a null value in a certain field per row first off, and secondly how you'd retrieve a certain value (ie valueIWant = dr["column3"].ToString(); )
I'm trying to retrieve values from different columns based upon certain criteria, take the sum and average, etc
It is actually quite a bit of data (the one that worked was like 300,000 rows and the big data set that didn't was closer to 8 million)